# What are the permissions needed for User which is used to connect a data source which is used in TypePerf windows utility?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

I am logging performance counter data to tables using [TypePerf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/typeperf) utility and i need to pass DSN(data source name). In DSN, I need to specify the user to connect to the server where i'll be logging my data. So what are the minimum permissions required by that user to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about the tool in question, I can only provide general advice.

It seems safe to assume the user will need, at a minimum:

- If a stored procedure is used to do the logging, then `EXECUTE` permissions on the stored procedure;
- If an `INSERT` query is used directly to do the logging instead of a stored procedure, then `INSERT` permissions on the table it's logging the data to.

That's the minimum; more permissions may be needed, but I'd start trying the minimum.

If you get errors, it's possible that more permissions may be needed. Possibilities include:

- `SELECT` and/or `UPDATE` on the logging table (if logging isn't always a simple `INSERT`);
- possibly access to other tables; check the stored procedure (if one exists) and/or any triggers on tables you're already interacting with. **Note**: in most cases, if the owner of the stored procedure is also the owner of any other tables being accessed, then no additional permissions should be needed.

An addendum, based on comments below: If the tool creates its own tables, it would need to have the `ddl-admin` role at the database level. It may only need that on the first run, it might need it on every run (if it tries to create the tables every time, or if different tables may be added depending on what happens).

Tables that are created by your process are owned by the user that runs it, and thus automatically have table-level rights to `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Once I run it with only ddl_admin rights, it seemed to create few tables in target db and then inserting records into them. so i believe it checks for the tables each time it inserts a log. It worked for now.

Comment: As the creator of the tables, your process would automatically be able to insert into them. And yes, if the process is trying to create tables, it would probably need ddl-admin rights.